# Top K Frequent Elements Solution (Leetcode)

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm working on understanding a standard solution for a problem with the following name: *Top K Frequent Elements* where we are expected to return a resultant array of the Top K frequent elements. The problem can be found here:
https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/

I have provided a standard solution for it (which passes all test cases below)

However, I am concerned about why the solution requires me to iterate through the *keySet* and why I can't iterate through the `nums` array instead. For instance, instead of having

```
         for(int n : map.keySet()) {
            int freq = map.get(n);
            if(bucket[freq] == null) {
                bucket[freq] = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
            }
            bucket[freq].add(n); 
        }
```

wouldn't the same result be acquired if we do the following?

```
       for(int n : nums) {
            int freq = map.get(n);
            if(bucket[freq] == null) {
                bucket[freq] = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
            }
            bucket[freq].add(n); 
        }
```

```
class Solution {
    public int[] topKFrequent(int[] nums, int k) {
        
        /*
        Bucket will be created where frequency of an element will act as the index, and all elements of that frequency 
        will be stored in a list referred to by that index. For example, every number with frequency 2 will be stored at
        bucket[2] in a list that bucket[2] refers to.
        */
        
        List<Integer>[] bucket = new ArrayList[nums.length+1]; 
        
        //the frequency of each element stored in map. 
        var map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
        for(int n : nums) map.put(n, map.getOrDefault(n, 0)+1); 
        
        //==========================================================================
         //attain frequency of number 'n', and bucket[frequency] refers to list of items that have that frequency, so add. 
        for(int n : map.keySet()) {
            int freq = map.get(n);
            if(bucket[freq] == null) {
                bucket[freq] = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
            }
            bucket[freq].add(n); 
        }
        //==========================================================================
        
    //populating the result - simply iterating backwards in bucket since we want top k - higher freq elements stored @ end
        int[] res = new int[k];
        int resIndex = 0; 
        int counter = 0; 
        for(int i = bucket.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(bucket[i] != null) {
                for(int element : bucket[i]) {
                    res[counter++] = element;
                    if(counter == k) {
                        return res; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return res; 
    }
}
```

Ultimately, we are iterating through the elements, grabbing the frequency, and adding it to a list referred to by an index of *that* frequency. This logic seems to be consistent regardless of whether I dry-run through *nums* or *keySet()*, and yet I get a wrong answer if I iterate through *nums*...

Thank you in advance for your insight.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). For us to help you, provide a  **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maps have unique keys, so when you do

```
 for(int n : map.keySet()) {
```

you correctly consider each distinct element in the input.

When you do

```
for(int n : nums) {
```

you no longer consider distinct elements. But that's wrong--the output is supposed to have only distinct elements. Your bucket `ArrayList`s should contain only unique integers that appear a certain number of times, not a list of every number that went into producing that count. When they contain non-distinct elements, the line

```
for(int element : bucket[i]) {
```

generates incorrect output containing all elements from the input rather than distinct ones.

Comment: Thank you! This completely resolved my doubts. I can't believe I overlooked this detail. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Ramkrishna Sharma - consider marking this answer as 'accepted' to give the proper credit to the contributor and also indicate that the issue is now resolved.